# Ejabberd module with child process

Tags: concurrency, erlang, ejabberd

I created a logging module which logs messages to a mysql db, the current code is located here:
https://github.com/amiadogroup/mod_log_chat_mysql5/blob/master/src/mod_log_chat_mysql5.erl

The Problem with the current code is, that sometimes the connection gets closed and as a result, the module doesn't work anymore.
As you see in the code, I store the DBRef in an ets table, which is not really the good way to go.

I asked the erlang mailinglist about this and they suggested me to do the DB Connection as an own child process of the module. This would enable the module to gracefully restart the connection upon closing of the connection.

Now my question is: how can I implement this child process with gen_server and/or gen_mod?

Do I need to create two files or can I do it within the same file?

Is there any example somewhere on how I could achieve that?

**Edit:** As you can see in the linked github repo, I updated the code and it works now, weeha!
Looking at the mod_Archive code helped me a lot, although I didn't decide to upgrade my ejabberd version.

I ran into another, but related problem now. In the code you see that I do an initial query with "SET NAMES UTF8" to prevent garbling of messages. It seems that this isn't done again if the gen_server does a reconnect. Is there any hook I can call upon reconnect so that the UTF8 query is done everytime?

**Edit#2:**
Now I switched to Emysql (https://github.com/Eonblast/Emysql) and it works out of the box by specifying the encoding directly on connect. 
Code is on github.

Thanks for your help,
Michael

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your source code you are only applying the gen_mod behaviour, if you do wish to have a gen_server you can do it in the same module, if you define the gen_server behaviour has well.

A good example would be the ejabberd module [mod_archive](http://svn.process-one.net/ejabberd-modules/mod_archive/trunk/src/mod_archive.erl), which implements both behaviours.

---

Edit: I never really worked "directly" with mysql on erlang. But through the ejabberd methods I find it pretty "easy"(you will have to make a few setup, but rather easy). You have the method

```
ejabberd_odbc:sql_query_t(Query)
```

And has an example you can find it on the module [mod_archive_odbc](http://svn.process-one.net/ejabberd-modules/mod_archive/trunk/src/mod_archive_odbc.erl).

To use that method(and the last module) I haved downloaded the mysql native driver and put the beams created from the driver in ejabberd ebin dir (you can put it anywhere has long is on the erlang path).
A a soft link to the ejabberd ebin is my favorite:

```
ln -s <diryouhavethedriver>/ebin/*.beam /usr/lib/ejabberd/ebin/
```

and do a few configurations on you ejabberd.cfg. This process is described on [this page on process one](https://support.process-one.net/doc/display/MESSENGER/Using+ejabberd+with+MySQL+native+driver). Notice that the full steps are to make mysql the full database of ejabberd. You may not want that, so you must jump a few steps.
Hope this help.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. With gen_server I'd start the db connection? How could I obtain then the db reference?

Comment: Edit the Answer to include a bit about mysql, hope it help

Comment: Thanks Nuno.

Regarding erlang_odbc: The problem here is, that I'm using Debian on the server side with the ejabberd deb of apt. And as far as I know, the deb isn't compiled with odbc support in it. 
Do you know if I compile the MySQL module on my own, can I still use the erlang_odbc module? I never tried that but I don't think it works :(

Comment: It may be different from version to version, but the ejabberd that is using mysql was installed from repositories from Ubuntu 11.04, and before this one I had it in another machine with a previous ubuntu version. Just don't remember which. 
At first I tough that I would need to compile it from source, but I gave it a go and all worked fine.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you look into general Erlang/OTP principles (gen_server, supervisor, etc).
ejabberd is relying on this standard Erlang architecture pattern.

Regarding your comment on database, ejabberd has its own way on managing database and passing queries to MySQL for example. You should as well look into it.

Comment: About Erlang/OTP: I'm currently doing this using the Erlang book of o'reilly. But I'm not yet very confident if I understood it correctly ;)

Regarding the own way about the db: See my comment below

Comment: Actually, we do not recommend using the Debian package: Either our binary package or build from source.